# How to deploy Path

Tags: deployment, metadata, ant

I'm trying to deploy custom Path using ANT. I have deployed the `pathAssistant` and the `flexipage`metadata but the Path is still not visible in setup nor on page layout. I can see that `pathAssistant` metadata are actually not moved to next sandbox for some reason.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you do a retrieve from the target org, can you retrieve the things you've pushed? If you do a comparison using https://gearset.com (free trial...) then it should highlight anything you've missed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You're right, the `pathAssistant` metadata are note build to the next sandbox. The question now is why.

Comment: I'd suggest trying a comparison with Gearset (full disclosure I'm CEO...) but that will probably help you build a deployable package (You can then download it and examine it with ANT to learn what was going wrong...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem, I attempted to deploy the path with the flexipage, but same deal... Can I ask if you're using a record type for your path and whether you've included the picklist you're using with the Path?

Once I included pathAssistant type in the package.xml it worked good!

Answer (score -2):

You need to enable the path settings in package.xml if you haven't.
if deploy fails, use standard values for picklist instead of custom ones

Comment: What do you mean by "enable the path settings in package.xml"?